# Distribute values evenly in range

Tags: excel-formula

How do I calculate and distribute the values evenly between 78.000 and 215.000 in the spreadsheet below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **B2** enter:

```
=(B$21-$B$1)/(21-1)+B1
```

and copy downwards.

[image]

Each value is exactly 6850 greater than the value above it.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved in a generic way as follows (refer to the screenshot) :

1. Calculate number equal length intervals for a given number of observations as `(count -1)` shown in C2.
2. Calculate Bin_Size, i.e. length of each interval as `(larger_num - smaller_num)/(count-1)` as shown in D2.
3. Calculate number at ith position as `n_i = n_(i-1) + bin_size` (as shown in B2).

Drag the formula in cell B2 down to the penultimate observation to fill in remaining values.

[image]